# Is there a difference between "use warnings;" and "use warnings 'all';"?

Tags: perl

I have the habit of starting each and every of my scripts with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

But some of the high-rep fellows here recommend

```
use warnings 'all';
```

If I understood them right, the latter is even better than the first. So I read through the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) and found

> All warnings are enabled in a block by either of these:
>
> ```
> use warnings;
> use warnings 'all';
> ```

Even the [Camel Book](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/prog/ch31_22.htm) says nothing different:

> ```
> use warnings;   # same as importing "all"
> ```

So

- *is* there a difference, or
- is it just more future-proof (in case future versions of Perl issue warnings we aren't aware of right now and `use warnings;` won't catch), or
- is it just another habit, like e.g. `ps -ef` vs. `ps aux`? Some people use this while others prefer the other.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Currently,

```
use warnings;
```

is equivalent to

```
use warnings 'all';
```

However, there has been [talk on perl5porters](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2015/06/msg228400.html) of changing it to mean

```
use warnings 'default';
```

New "less-critical" warnings would be added to the "all" category but not shown by default. Since it seems this change is seriously being considered, it's safer to `use warnings 'all';` explicitly.

Previous discussions on p5p:

[*RFC: Support for new warning categories outside of "all"*](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2014/06/msg217115.html)

[*I've added support for new warning categories outside of "all" to blead*](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2014/12/msg224127.html)

Comment: The link you gave was the crucial point. So for private use I'll be the _Charley_ guy (from the [discussion you mentioned](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2015/06/msg228467.html)) and `use warnings 'all';` which will give new and yet unknown warnings in the future while for office use I'll do as _Tallulah_ would and stick with `use warnings;` and be more conservative.

Comment: Re "*it's safer to `use warnings 'all';` explicitly*, Especially for the less experienced Perl programmers, as these will get the most benefit from the stricter warnings. That's why I've been promoting `use warnings 'all';` on SO. [I oppose the change because it's unrealistic to expect less experienced Perl programmers to know to use `use warnings 'all';` instead of just `use warnings;` given the extent of the documentation suggesting the latter. It's also a backwards incompatible change to those that were promised that `use warnings;` would turn on all warnings.]

Comment: Just wanted to ask the same question! And while the answer is great, i hope that such change **will be never happened**. Time-to-time I hate some perl porters. ;(

Answer (score 2):

One is more explicit than the other, but as noted in the documentation, they have the same effect.  It's probably better to use the `'all'` import list to make it more clear that all warnings are in fact enabled.  This is also helpful for those who may be new to Perl.  When in doubt, explicit is usually better than implicit.