# Assign zero to scalar variable in Perl

Tags: perl

How to assign 0 to scalar variable in Perl? 
My code :

```
$x=0;

if(!$x)
{
   print "fail";
}
else
{
  print "pass";
}
```

Output : Fail

Comment: You need to print `pass`

Comment: Why are you expecting `0` to be a true value? It counts as false in Perl.

Comment: Please don't change your question significantly after you've gotten answers. Because of your edit, Sobrique's answer no longer makes sense, and anybody who visits this page in the future will be confused about where `!x` is coming from. That's why you should always copy-and-paste the exact code you're using, or even better, create a [mcve] that reproduces your issue.

Comment: [As one would expect](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/perl/649/true-and-false#t=20170221180326021372). What's the question?

Answer (score 3):

Turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings;` and it'll tell you that `!x` is wrong:

> Bareword "x" not allowed while "strict subs" in use

It should be `! $x` - or by my preference, `not $x`.

You should ALWAYS `use strict;` and `use warnings 'all';`.

Comment: Where did this `warnings 'all'` meme come from? I've seen it a few times here on SO (but never "in the wild"). I've always used `use warnings;`.

Comment: @melpomene a couple of us do that, but not 'all' of us. I don't, for example. But having more warnings than the usual can't hurt really.

Comment: @simbabque The weird thing is that they're identical: You don't get more warnings with `use warnings 'all'` ([`perldoc warnings`](https://metacpan.org/pod/warnings#DESCRIPTION): "*All warnings are enabled in a block by either of these*").

Comment: This is in preparation for a time to come, when _additional_ warnings may be added, but not included in the 'defaults'. Doesn't make any difference now; might later.

Comment: @melpomene There has been [serious discussion](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2015/06/msg228400.html) on p5p about changing `use warnings;` to mean something like `use warnings 'default';`, where the "default" category doesn't include everything.

Comment: @melpomene See _[Is there a difference between “use warnings;” and “use warnings 'all';”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38162364/5830574)_. I already had the very same question.

Answer (score -1):

So, it is being assigned, but you are asking Perl the wrong question.  You are asking, "is $x false?" and since zero equals false in Perl, Perl says true.   What you want to know is, did $x get assigned zero.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $x=0;

if ( not defined $x || $x != 0 ) {
   print "fail";
} else {
  print "pass";
}
```

This prints `pass`.

And, as noted by my colleagues, always use `use strict;` and `use warnings;` and when you do that, you'll also need to add a `my` in front of your `$x`.

Hopefully this clarifies things.